# Privilege to select only user's own tuple only in mysql

Tags: mysql

I create a table named person which columns such as name, sex, occupation and so on.
I want to give each user select grant over that user’s own tuple only. I assume that each users use their own name as their user ID.
So I created view as

> create view mine as select * from person where name=current_user;

And I give privilege all user

> grant select on mine to public;

But it does not work. 
How to grant privilege to all user in mysql?

And, in the person table, name column  store only just name. But current_user replies name@localhost. So it does not match. How to solve that?

Comment: yes. I mean row.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably make use of `LEFT` and `INSTR` built in functions to strip out the host name from the `user@host`.

```
CREATE VIEW mine 
AS 
SELECT * FROM person 
 WHERE `name`=LEFT(CURRENT_USER(),INSTR(current_user(), '@')-1);
```

Comment: Yes, It works. Thank you. But how to grant the access right to public? Is there a way or just I have to grant 100 persons 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not solve all problems.  And some of the problems it *can* solve are rather messy to code.  I suggest you implement the solution to this problem in your application.